# AutoMapper mapping null-able value types

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

AutoMapper doesn't seem to map null nullable values. It will only map the properties if the nullable value.

How do I tell AutoMapper to always map null values (of any kind) from the source to the destination?

**EDIT:**

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Mappers/MapperRegistry.cs

The AssignableMapper is before the NullableMapper which prevents nullable types from getting mapped if the source is null.

I added this snippet of code to insert a NullableMapper at the very beginning.

```
container.RegisterSingle(() =>
            {
                // we need to add a nullable mapper to ensure Nullable<value> gets mapped correctly
                var mappers = AutoMapper.Mappers.MapperRegistry.AllMappers().ToList();
                mappers.Insert(0, new AutoMapper.Mappers.NullableMapper());
                return mappers.AsEnumerable();
            });
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Can you check out the latest pre-release version on NuGet?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this cannot be so easily configured. I have tried this:

```
var r = (IObjectMapper[])typeof(MappingEngine).GetField("_mappers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(((MappingEngine)(AutoMapper.Mapper.Engine)));

Array.Resize(ref r, r.Length + 1);
Array.Copy(r, 0, r, 1, r.Length - 1);
r[0] = new NullableMapper();

typeof(MappingEngine).GetField("_mappers", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(((MappingEngine)(AutoMapper.Mapper.Engine)), r);
```

And even this:

```
MapperRegistry.AllMappers = () => new IObjectMapper[]
{
    new NullableMapper(),
    new TypeMapMapper(TypeMapObjectMapperRegistry.AllMappers()),
    new StringMapper(),
    new FlagsEnumMapper(),
    new AssignableMapper(),
    new EnumMapper(),
    new PrimitiveArrayMapper(),
    new ArrayMapper(),
    new EnumerableToDictionaryMapper(),
    new DictionaryMapper(),
    new ReadOnlyCollectionMapper(),
    new CollectionMapper(),
    new EnumerableMapper(),
    new NullableSourceMapper(),
    new ImplicitConversionOperatorMapper(),
    new ExplicitConversionOperatorMapper(),
};
```

And non of this helped me. It still throws exceptions of wrong null-typed mapping when it just should map null to the property.